# Create superID column from two Id columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a data frame as

```
data <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5), b=c(1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6))

    a   b
    1   1
    1   2
    2   2
    2   3
    3   3
    3   4
    4   5
    5   6
```

now I want to generate master column C as following:

```
    a   b  c
    1   1  1
    1   2  1
    2   2  1
    2   3  1
    3   3  1
    3   4  1
    4   5  2
    5   6  3
```

This is generally updating values(ID) of column a and column b from their intermediate ids.
e.g **column a** has 1 corresponding value in **column b** is 1, now search for all values which have 1 in **column b** and assign those **master id** 1, simillarly another row having Id 1 in **column a** have corresponding **column b**=2 so search for all 2 in **column b** and assign master id. and vice versa.

I have done following code but it goes only 1 roatation: **column a to column b and b to a**

```
  masterCombine <- function(data, col1="a", col2="b", masterName="c"){

  skipList <- NULL

  masterId <- 1

  for( p in 1: nrow(data)){
    ind <- ind1 <- ind2 <- ind3 <- ind4 <- NULL
    if(!p %in% skipList){

      ind1 <- which(data[, col1] == data[, col1][p])
      for( ij in ind1){
        ind2 <-  which(data[ ,col2] == data[ ,col2][ij])
        for(j in ind2){
          ind3<- which(data[ , col1] == data[ ,col1][j])
          ind4 <- append(ind4, ind3)
        }

      }

      ind <- unique(append(ind1,ind4))
      skipList <- append(skipList, ind)
      data[ind, masterName] <- masterId

      masterId <-  masterId + 1
    }
  }

  return(data)
}
```

**How do I Acheive this recursive matching?**

Comment: I didn't understand neither the logic or the desired output at all.

Comment: If what you're seeking is a numeric column of unique id's, I would think `as.numeric(factor(paste0(D$a, "-", D$b)))` would be the easiest solution.

Comment: yes. I will give u example:
It starts from 1, meaning both a and b list have values=1.
now traverse through a: search for 1's. and corresponding b's ids.
In my avobe eg. second 1 has b id=2. So all 2 in b are equal to 1.
Now traverse for 2 in b and assign those masterId 1, but corresponding "a" id for 2 is 2. then againg search for "b" id for a's 2 are 2 and 3. and so on . This will continue until u get only 1 corresponding Id.

Comment: @Benjamin: No I want output as column c only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this with the `igraph` package and its `clusters()` function. You just need to make sure first that the values in column `a` are recorded distinctly to the column `b` values.

```
library(igraph)
data <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5), b=c(1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6))
newdata <- mapply(paste0, names(data), data)
g <- graph.edgelist(newdata)
clusters(g)$membership
#a1 b1 b2 a2 b3 a3 b4 a4 b5 a5 b6 
# 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  3  3 

cg <- clusters(g)$membership
data$c <- cg[match(newdata[,"a"],names(V(g)))]

#  a b c
#1 1 1 1
#2 1 2 1
#3 2 2 1
#4 2 3 1
#5 3 3 1
#6 3 4 1
#7 4 5 2
#8 5 6 3
```

For visual folk, here's the graphical representation from `plot(g)`

[image]

Comment: Your code worked for above case, but its not universal. Because when I change column a's last row to 4; c value should have come 1 same like 7th row as it cotains 4 in col a. But yours code gives all zero values in column c.

Comment: @indra_patil - fixed now.

Comment: Nice one. `igraph` is always first in my learning queue, but somehow can't force myself to learn it.

Comment: @davidarenburg - its a great package for this sort of thing. I just keep trying all its different functions until I hit one that makes sense for the problem. There's lots I'm naive about with it.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is. But need to get used to the syntax. And have pretty steep learning curve. I guess similar to `data.table`

Comment: @thelatemail This worked, cool use of igraph. But This works fine in R version 3.1.0 , and not in 3.1.2. 
clusters(g)$membership doesnt have names so last step of matching producing NA result.

Comment: @indra_patil - it works on R 3.2.1 with igraph 1.0.0, it seems strange that it would have reverted and then changed back.

Comment: @thelatemail: Is there any other way to find these attribute names?

>> clusters(g)$membership <<

Comment: @indra_patil - `cg[match(newdata[,"a"],V(g)$name)]` will do it also, as will `cg[match(newdata[,"a"],names(V(g)))]`

Comment: @thelatemail: but latest version of igraph  doesn't have names to cluster$attributes..  Any other solution to above question bro??

Comment: @indra_patil - none of the alternative solutions require the cluster to have names. They use the names of the vertices. Did you try the two alternatives in my comment?

Comment: @thelatemail: yes I tried both but In both cases returns NA values. :(

Comment: @indra_patil - I've tested my above code on the latest igraph 1.01 and it works just fine. The `clusters(g)` result has names, as does `V(g)` - did you run the code using character strings for the data in each column? They won't have names if you use numeric data for `a` and `b`.