# Group the text if union

Tags: r, text, grouping

Here is my data:

```
ITEM <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E","F","G","G","G")
LOCATION <- c("aaa","bbb","ccc","bbb","fff","ggg","zzz","zzz","eee","hhh","iii","kkk","jjj","iii","iii","yyy","xxx")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ITEM,LOCATION))

Long Form:
       ITEM LOCATION
    1     A      aaa
    2     A      bbb
    3     A      ccc
    4     B      bbb
    5     B      fff
    6     B      ggg
    7     B      zzz
    8     C      zzz
    9     C      eee
    10    D      hhh
    11    D      iii
    12    E      kkk
    13    E      jjj
    14    F      iii
    15    G      iii
    16    G      yyy
    17    G      xxx
```

Wide Form (easier to read):

```
ITEM LOCATION.1 LOCATION.2 LOCATION.3 LOCATION.4
A        aaa        bbb        ccc       <NA>
B        bbb        fff        ggg        zzz
C        zzz        eee       <NA>       <NA>
D        hhh        iii       <NA>       <NA>
E        kkk        jjj       <NA>       <NA>
F        iii       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
G        iii        yyy        xxx       <NA>
```

Originally I was grouping the Item manually when the locations have intersected.

i.e. I will group into {A,B,C},{D,F,G},{E}

My raw data have 8000 rows and it takes me several days to do this.
When the dataset is small, I can use the left join and get the desired output
but when the dataset is large, I cannot use that.

Is there any package can group the element by union?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are making intersections?  You want to find where "ITEM" intersects with "LOCATION"?  Strictly speaking, upper case "A" does't have an intersection with lower case "a".  In example, where does {D,F,G} come from?  or {E}?

Comment: the intersection is only focusing on the "LOCATION". For example, Item A and B has intersection at "bbb" and item B and C has intersection at "zzz". so A B C will be a group. I discover a package called "igraph" but I don't know how to group in this case. thanks @Soren

Comment: @TungManLok - see `igraph::clusters` - `clusters(graph.data.frame(df))`

Comment: do you need `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(ITEM) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% spread(id, LOCATION)` ?

Comment: @TungManLok I've proposed a solution below.  Still not fully clear on the groups. Eg, you note "Item A and B has intersection at "bbb" and item B and C has intersection at "zzz". so A B C will be a group" but in your data.frame input example, ITEM "C" doesn't have any intersection, so it's not clear why ABC is a group?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114897/create-superid-column-from-two-id-columns/32116154

Answer (score 5):

```
#Convert columns to character to avoid complications later
df$ITEM = as.character(df$ITEM)
df$LOCATION = as.character(df$LOCATION)

#Split ITEM by LOCATION and convert each sub-group into data.frame
#by making the first element of each sub-group 'from' and all elements 'to'
df1 = do.call(rbind,
              lapply(split(df$ITEM, df$LOCATION), function(x)
                  data.frame(from = x[1], to = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))

library(igraph)
#Convert the data.frame df1 into graph
g = graph.data.frame(df1)
#Use 'clusters' to identify the separate groups
#and 'groups' to extract the vertices (in this case, ITEM)
groups(clusters(g))
#$`1`
#[1] "A" "C" "B"

#$`2`
#[1] "D" "G" "F"

#$`3`
#[1] "E"
```

You could also remove the `LOCATION` at the end (based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349437/group-the-text-if-union/55349815#comment97423626_55349437) to your question)

```
lapply(groups(clusters(graph.data.frame(df))), function(x) x[x %in% df$ITEM])
#$`1`
#[1] "A" "B" "C"

#$`2`
#[1] "D" "F" "G"

#$`3`
#[1] "E"
```